# How to deal with loss of "Create Snapshot" in Xcode 7.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

To my great disappointment, I've found that Xcode 7 no longer has the "Create Snapshot" command for creating a good backup copy of a project for recovery purposes. In fact, it doesn't have a "Restore Snapshot" command, either, so all of the many, many project Snapshot files that I've taken can apparently no longer be read and used(!).

I understand that Git and Xcode Snapshots are "totally separate" things ([git vs xcode snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531655/git-vs-xcode-snapshot)), so apparently I can't use Git to develop a Git-based equivalent to the old Xcode 'Snapshot' capability or to read old 'Snapshot' files?

Is there any solution to bring back a 'Snapshot'-like capability and read my old 'Snapshot' files, or do I just have to give up and rely on the Git commands under Xcode's ">Source Control" menu?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you still can, indeed, fallback to the command-line, and do a [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

That will create a compressed image of a snapshot of your project.